# Google Cloud Functions - How to force a function to scale the number of instances?

Tags: asynchronous, google-cloud-functions, python-asyncio

I have a backtesting function that I need to run with several hundreds possible combinations of parameters. Running it sequentially on my laptop would be very time consuming, so I deployed the function to Google Cloud hoping I could take advantage of scaling across multiple instances to handle multiple requests in parallel.

I wrote a short script to submit asynchronous requests, something like this:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for (param1, param2, param3) in pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2, 3], [4, 6, 8], [8, 10, 12]]):
            payload = {
                    'param1': param1,
                    'param2': param2,
                    'param3': param3,
            }
            await session.post(url, json=payload)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Of course I have more parameters than that, but the loop construct is the same. I started the script and judging by the artifacts appearing in the storage bucket the requests were handled sequentially. I checked the function metrics and the number of instances had been oscillating between 1 and 2 since the requests were submitted. While the requests were still pending I opened the function details and set the maximum number of instances to 3000 which triggered re-deployment, but eventually changed nothing and with the new settings the number of instances was still 1 or 2, and pending requests continued to be handled sequentially.

My questions are:

- Is this an expected behavior given that the maximum number of
  instances was set to 3000?
- Under what circumstances more instances
  would be provisioned for the function?
- The function was deployed with
  HTTP trigger - would it make a difference if it was the Pub/Sub
  trigger?
- I want to achieve the parallel execution (not necessarily
  3000 instances at time, but definitely more than 2) - is it possible
  with Google Cloud Functions or shall I rather look at a different
  product from their cloud platform?

I am fairly new to serverless on GCP, so any insights or advice are greatly appreciated.

Comment: As written, your code is essentially synchronous. `await` is blocking, so your for loop makes each request and then waits for it to complete before making the next one. You’ll need to use something like `asyncio.gather` if you want to allow multiple requests at a time.

Answer (score 1):

As per @dim 's comment all I had to do was to use `asyncio.gather`, so I changed my code that submits requests to something like this:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def submit_func(session, url, payload):
    async with session.post(url, json=payload) as resp:
        result = await resp.text()

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for (param1, param2, param3) in pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2, 3], [4, 6, 8], [8, 10, 12]]):
            payload = {
                    'param1': param1,
                    'param2': param2,
                    'param3': param3,
            }
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(submit_func(session, url, payload)))

        resluts = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


asyncio.run(main())
```

The code was inspired by the example from [this blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/asynchronous-http-requests-in-python-with-aiohttp).

I can confirm that submitting requests to Google Cloud Function using `asyncio.gather` results in parallel processing and scaling out by employing additional active instances (if needed) on the platform side.